# iOS In App Purchase Non Renewing Subscription Receipt Validation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am trying to understand if it is possible (or not), from within an app targeted at iOS7, to check if a Non Renewing Subscription receipt has been cancelled by Apple?

I thought there was a way to check for a Cancellation Date in the receipt, however, I can't see how you can re-request a Non Renewing Subscription receipt?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For information, I have found that if a receipt is verified against the AppStore servers there is a field cancellation_date within the formatted data from the receipt that is returned.

So, if you post the receipt from your main bundle up to Apple to verify, the returned data will show any cancellation date. If this date is present Apple state to treat the transaction as never having occurred. See here for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1